# How to deploy rails 5 on digitalocean 16.04 one click app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, digital-ocean, puma

I make a droplet on digital ocean and select rails 16.04 one click app.

Then done all project changes after clone
like bundle install , database.yml changes , migrations , assets precompile. All done fine

Now I don't know where to replace demo_name with my project name in `nginx` and `puma` settings and how to restart `puma` also

Please help thanks

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean#update-nginx-configuration

Comment: Change root location like shown in the tutorial above

Answer (score 1):

Install `passenger gem` and add lines in your nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 67.205.128.137;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/app_name/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby;
}
```

Restart nginx by command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```